# Tengo un datatable que no se siempre se actualiza

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatable

tengo una pagina php que muestra una Datatable para "surtir" un producto al presionar el Checkbox que se encuentra en la fila. Al irlos seleccionando se va creando dinámicamente una segunda tabla que al presionar el botón Surtir ejecuta una llamada AJax mediante POST y al regresar con éxito refresca el Datatable. Esto lo hace siempre y cuando el número de filas seleccionada no sea mayor a 30, por ejemplo si intento seleccionar 100 filas, realiza correctamente su actividad pero no refresca de manera correcta el Datatable hasta que se recarga la página.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head><meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- DataTables CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.21/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.css"/>
   
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css /> 
   
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sistema.inomac.mx/utils/style.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    
            
<div class="container">
  <h2>Gestion Salida de Almacen</h2> 
    <div id="mensaje"></div>
    <div id="respuesta" class="container">    
      <h2>Productos a entregar</h2>
        <table id="xhr_tabla" class="table table-sm table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size:12px;">
            <thead bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>Producto</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>TOTAL</th><th>Unidad de Medida</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="enviar">
         <a class="btn btn-success btnSurtir" id= "btnSurtir" href="" role="button">Surtir</a>
    </div>
    <p> </p>
    <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="listaSalidas" name="listaSalidas" class="table table-responsive  table-hover table-responsive-sm" width="100%" style="font-size:12px">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>No. Apli.</th>
            <th>Id. Rancho</th>
            <th>Rancho</th>
            <th>Tabla</th>
            <th>Id. Prod.</th>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Unidad de Medida</th>
            <th>Surtir</th>
          </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        </tbody> 
      </table>
      
  </div>
</div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- DataTables --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.21/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/funciones.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### FUNCIONES.JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let arr_filas = [] ;
    let totales = [] ;
    opcion = 4;
    
    var x = document.getElementById("enviar");
    x.style.display = "none";
    
    document.getElementById("respuesta").style.display = "none";
    
    listaSalidas = $('#listaSalidas').DataTable({ 
          responsive: true,
          "processing": true,
          pagingType: 'full_numbers',
          "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Primero",
                        "sLast":"Último",
                        "sNext":"Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
               },
               "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
                },
    "ajax":{            
        "url": "modelo/modelo.php", 
        "method": 'POST', //usamos el metodo POST
//        "data":{opcion:opcion}, //enviamos opcion 4 para que haga un SELECT
        "dataSrc":""
    },
    "columns":[
        {"data": "fecha"},
        {"data": "id_aplica"},
        {"data": "num_subrancho"},
        {"data": "rancho"},
        {"data": "tabla"},
        {"data": "id_prod"},
        {"data": "nom_prod"},
        {"data": "dosis_total"},
        {"data": "unidad_medida"},
        {"defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' class='Chk_Agregar'></div>"}
    ]
});     
    
    
    $(document).on("click", ".Chk_Agregar", function(){
        fila_tabla = $(this).closest("tr");         
        id = parseInt(fila_tabla.find('td:eq(1)').text()); //capturo el ID
        rancho = fila_tabla.find('td:eq(3)').text();
        tabla = fila_tabla.find('td:eq(4)').text();
        id_prod = parseInt(fila_tabla.find('td:eq(5)').text());
        prod = fila_tabla.find('td:eq(6)').text();
        cantidad = parseFloat(fila_tabla.find('td:eq(7)').text());
        medida = fila_tabla.find('td:eq(8)').text();
        
        let result = arr_filas.filter(fila => fila.id == id);  //busca id para saber si existe
         
        if (result.length <= 0) {      // si no existe en el arreglo, lo agrega
            arr_filas.push({id: id, rancho:rancho, tabla:tabla, id_prod:id_prod, producto: prod, cantidad: cantidad, unidad: medida});    //agrega elemento al final del arreglp
            totaliza(prod, cantidad, 1) ;
        } else {
            let pos = arr_filas.findIndex(el => el.id == id ) ;   //enceuntra la posici贸n del elemento en el arreglo
            arr_filas.splice(pos, 1) ;                           //elimina el elemento en la posici贸n indicada
            totaliza(prod, cantidad, 0) ;
        }
        //ordenando por nombre de producto
        arr_filas.sort(function (a, b){
            if (a.producto > b.producto) {
                return 1 ;
            }
            if (a.producto < b.producto) {
                return -1 ;
            }
            return 0 ;
        } ) ;
        
        //Escribiendo datos a la tabla
        $("#xhr_tabla>tbody tr").remove();
        let cont = 0 ;
        let fila = "" ;
        for(let i = 0 ; i < arr_filas.length ; i++){
            let result = totales.filter(fila => fila.producto == arr_filas[i].producto);  //busca si existe en el arreglo
            if (cont === 0) {
                fila = "<tr><td align='center' rowspan='" + result[0].num_filas + "'>" + arr_filas[i].producto + "</td><td align='center'>" + arr_filas[i].cantidad + "</td><td align='center' rowspan='" + result[0].num_filas + "'>" + result[0].monto + "</td><td align='center' rowspan='" + result[0].num_filas + "'>" + arr_filas[i].unidad + "</td></tr>" ;
                console.log(fila) ;
            } else {
                fila = "<tr><td align='center'>"  + arr_filas[i].cantidad + "</td></tr>" ;            
            }
            $("#xhr_tabla>tbody").append(fila);
            cont++ ;
            if (cont == result[0].num_filas) {
                cont = 0 ;
            }
        }    
        
        //visualizando la tabla de salidas seleccionadas
        if(arr_filas.length > 0) {
            x.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("respuesta").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("respuesta").style.display = "none";
        }
    });
    
    function totaliza(prod, cantidad, tipo){
    //totalizando por producto

        let result = totales.filter(fila => fila.producto == prod);  //busca si existe en el arreglo
        let pos = totales.findIndex(el => el.producto == prod) ;  //ubica la posici贸n en el arreglo
        
        if (result.length <= 0 || tipo == 1) {    //si no existe lo agrega
            if (pos < 0) {
                totales.push({producto: prod, monto: cantidad, num_filas: 1}) ;
            } else {
                totales[pos].monto += cantidad ;
                totales[pos].num_filas += 1 ;
            }
        } else {
            totales[pos].monto -= cantidad ; 
            totales[pos].num_filas -= 1 ;
        }
    }
    
    $("#btnSurtir").click(function(){
      //  alert("SURTR") ;
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr_filas);
        
         $.ajax({
          url: "modelo/registro_salida.php",
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",    
          data:  {data:jsonString}
         })
            .done(function(data) {
                    if(data.success){
                        alert("Filas: " + data.filas);
                        //listaSalidas.ajax.reload(null, false);
                        console.log(data.filas);
                        $('#listaSalidas').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    } else{
                        alert("Error: " + data,filas);
                    }
                    console.log(data.responseCode) ;
                } )
            .pipe(function(data) {
                    return data.responseCode != 200 ?
                    $.Deferred().reject( data ) :
                    data;
                } )
            .fail(function(data) {
                    if ( data.responseCode )
                        console.log( data.responseCode );
                } ); 
    
               
    } ) ;
    
});    // on_ready
```

### MODELO.PHP

```
<?php

    include_once("../../../conectar/conecta.php") ;

    $hoy = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d") ;
  
    $consulta = "select id_aplica, aplicaciones.num_subrancho, subrancho.nombre as rancho, tabla, aplicaciones.id_prod, nom_prod, fecha, dosis_total, unidad_medida, aplicaciones.status from aplicaciones,subrancho, producto where aplicaciones.id_prod = producto.id_prod and aplicaciones.num_subrancho = subrancho.num_subrancho and aplicaciones.status='Programada' order by fecha DESC" ;
   
    $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
    $resultado->execute();        
    $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  
    print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);//envio el array final el formato json a AJAX
  
    $connect->close();
?>
```

### REGISTRO_SALIDA.PHP

```
<?php
    include_once("../../../conectar/conecta.php") ;

    $array = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    
    $hoy = date("y")."/".date("m")."/".date("d") ;
    $tipo = "S" ;
    $status = "Entregada" ;
    $mensaje = "Surtido con Exito" ;

    $elementos = count($array)  ;
    
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $elementos ; $i++){
        $id_aplica = $array[$i]["id"] ;
        $subrancho = $array[$i]["rancho"] ;
        $sector = $array[$i]["tabla"] ;
        $id_prod =  $array[$i]["id_prod"] ;
        $nom_prod = $array[$i]["producto"] ;
        $cantidad = $array[$i]["cantidad"] ;

        $sql = " select existencia, clasificacion, costo_promedio from producto where id_prod = ".$id_prod ;
        $fila = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($fila);
        $existencia = $row[0] ;
        $clasificacion = $row[1] ;
        $precio = $row[2] ;
        
        $saldo = $existencia - $cantidad ;
            
        //registra el movimiento de salida de producto
        $sql2 = "insert into movtos_prod (id_prod, nom_prod, clasificacion, tipo, cantidad, precio_compra, fecha_movto, id_requisicion, subrancho, sector) values ('$id_prod', '$nom_prod', '$clasificacion', '$tipo', '$cantidad', '$precio', '$hoy', '$id_aplica', '$subrancho', '$sector')" ;
        $linea2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
    
        //actualiza en tabla producto costo y existencia
        $sql4 = "update producto set existencia=".$saldo." where id_prod=".$id_prod ;
        $linea3 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql4);
    
        //se actualiza estado de aplicacion
        $sql3 = "update aplicaciones set status = 'Entregada' where id_aplica= ".$id_aplica ;
        $linea4 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql3);
            
        $data = array(
            'success' =>true,
            'filas' => $mensaje
        );
    }
    
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data); 
  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que la solución más rápida, sería hacer que la página se recargue de manera automática, después de realizar la tarea de seleccionar las 100 o más filas.

Es necesario revisar el código, porque el error esta en la parte en la que se realiza la consulta que debería refrescar la tabla.